# Azure Devops - Build project, delete some files and zip a folder

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I'm starting on Azure Devops.

With Azure Devops, how can I delete some files after the solution build and before generate a zip file, but all this in the same step?

In the image step, do the solution build and generate a zip with the package, ready to deploy, but I need delete some files inside this zip file.

MSBuild process print screen with arguments:

[image: MSBuild process print screen with arguments]

Zip file with all files to be deployed in the server and the zip that I need delete some files:

[image: Zip file with all files to be deployed in the server and the zip that I need delete some files]

Maybe I will need unzip the package, delete the files and zip the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [MSBuild task](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Ftasks%2Fbuild%2Fmsbuild%3Fview%3Dazure-devops&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cad0cf259304f47201baa08d8bdba8483%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637467956123836635%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=JMjS5lToxsPiAcqBxbWv4Myh9BYUcBKrc%2FjGG%2FG70%2B4%3D&reserved=0) will build project with MSBuild. And reviewing this doc: [MSBuild Properties](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprevious-versions%2Fvisualstudio%2Fvisual-studio-2013%2Fgg433487(v%3Dvs.120)&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cad0cf259304f47201baa08d8bdba8483%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637467956123846627%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=y7THUiK4eaYtpbYlkuvq8xtKUd2CCk6yro0NyQWBvVs%3D&reserved=0) we find that currently there is no such argument implementing this feature.

In the meanwhile, we find this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment#excluding-specific-files-and-folders) guides how to exclude Files and Folders from a Web Package.